# How can i display Rows automatically in a datagridview when you select the Table in richTextbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, datagridview

When I click on the table I want to displays rows automatically in the datagridview and if I connect to antoher database i want that the same happens automatically

**The form:**

[image: The form]

**My Code:**

```
  try
         {

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCmd.Connection = connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            RichTextBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
            RichTextBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your DataGridView AutogenerateColumns to be True..and when you click ,add event to select database where table name you click.....

Comment: Can you give a Example off the add event